# Hooking functions in a VMProtect'ed executable

Tags: ollydbg, breakpoint, packers, vmprotect

I'm trying to solve the Sharif CTF 2016 HI2.exe challenge. This challenge requires a specific (impossible to reach) environment (64 processors, 128GB RAM, ...) to display the flag. As the executable is packed with `VMProtect`, the best alternative seems to hook functions responsible for the environment specification checks, and modify their return values at run time. I'm using OllyDbg with the StrongOD plugin. I have documented all details here: https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/SharifCTF-2016/hi.

I have achieved the first step (I have modified values of the `SYSTEM_INFO` structure manipulated by the `GetSystemInfo` function) but failed to reach my second breakpoint, set on the `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` function. The program displays the following error message before my 2nd BP is reached: `A debugger has been found running on your system`.

I have tried to play with a few options from the StrongOD plugin (HidePEB, KernelMode, SkipSomeExceptions) but it either doesn't change anything or crashes the executable before the 2nd BP.

How can I achieve this goal? How should I configure OllyDbg and/or StronOD to prevent the program from knowing it's being debugged?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You should try investigating what exacly the executable detects instead of blindly turning anti-debugging features on/off.

Answer (score 1):

`StrongOD` can have unexpected behaviour if you are using Win7 as your debugging environment. Try to use `ScyllaHide` plugin with the `VMProtect` profile on, ignore `Invalid or privileged instruction` exception in the debugging options.

Answer (score 1):

If there's no way to debug it, use system mechanisms to load your DLL into protected process, then do whatever you like.